# Could not find SDK "microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1,version=1.1"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

After an update of Visual studio 2015 I was this error and I can't open the designer.
I think that I must change the version build but I don't know how to change it 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF2a3.png)

Comment: Try doing a repair on Visual Studio 2015.  Sounds like something did not install right

Comment: I ran into a lot of SDK issues after Update 1 - could get it working for a couple days again by removing the SDKs via the Add/Remove Programs, the opening the solution, right-clicking the Universal App project and having Visual Studio install the missing components.  Unfortunately, ultimate fix for me was a re-install of Windows and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because a reference in one of my plugins was missing.

Have a look at your references in your uwp project (or others) in your solution and check if any references are missing.

I solved it by deleting the missing reference and restoring the NuGet packages of the solution(right click your solution -> Restore NuGet Packages).

That error occurs probably because the new update got rid of the reference, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

Could not find SDK "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1, Version=1.1"

And I have windows 10 Pro, build 14342.rs1_release.160506-1708 and Universal Windows Platform version 10.0.10240.0.

It worked for me when I deleted the reference and rebu